# How to create an ABSTRACT persistence layer in Spring?

Tags: spring, jpa, architecture, persistence, abstract

I need some help with this design issue I have in Spring. I must say I'm a newbie to Spring and Hibernate, JPA, etc.

We're creating a web application that is based on Spring and which is separated into different Maven modules. The modules are (the little arrow '->' means "references"):

- [1] project (the head of the application; pom)
- [2] core model (jpa annotations here)
- [3] core business logic (-> core model)
- [4] webapp (-> persistence, -> core business logic)
- [5] persistence abstract (-> core model)
- [6] persistence impl relational db (-> persistence abstract)
- [7] persistence impl xml file (-> persistence abstract)
- [8] persistence impl ...

With [5] we want to create an abstract persistence layer that defines some classes or abstract services (interfaces?) for persisting the business objects.

In [6] should be the implementation that uses Hibernate/JPA for persisting the business objects. As far as I understood Maven it is possible to use the JPA annotations in an other maven module, here [2]. Furthermore we want to have in [7] an implementation that persists the business objects into an xml-file, or an other source, what ever it might be in future.

Do you have an idea how to hide the actual persistence implementations from the web app module? What do I have to specify in [4] and [5] to use an architecture like this?

Our intention is to let the web app module only know about the abstract persistence module and have a configuration file there which desides which actual persistence type or storage source to use.

Is there a way to use Spring Data JPA in [6] and something else in [7]?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a bit of reading and diving into the world of design patterns I decided to do the following and share my experiences (please see my first post for resolving the references).

For the persistence layer ([5], [6], [7], etc.) I used the Strategy-Pattern, but you can also call it [DAOFactory-Pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) if you want to google it. In connection with that I used the [GenericDAO-Pattern](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects), which is very good explained in the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate".

The Strategy-Pattern basically consists of an interface, in my case called *PersistenceStrategy* abstracting the actual persistence implementation. Further I have a service *PersistenceService* which wraps that Persistency Strategy.

```
public interface PersistenceStrategy {
    public void persist(BaseEntity object);
    ...
}
```

The PersistenceService:

```
public class PersistenceService {

    private PersistenceStrategy persistenceStrategy;

    public void setPersistenceStrategy(PersistenceStrategy strategy) {
        this.persistenceStrategy = strategy;
    }

    public PersistenceStrategy getPersistenceStrategy() {
        return this.persistenceStrategy;
    }
}
```

The actual persistence classes [6] and [7] (e.g. PersistenceStrategyHibernate) etc. implement this interface and I declared them as a Spring bean. Also I declared the PersistenceService as a bean. The actual PersistenceStrategy is them injected to the PersistenceService. Please note that this bean definition is in the actual persistence implementation in [5] and [6] for instance, not in the webapp project [4].

```
<bean id="hibernatePersistenceStrategy" class="org.myProject.persistence.relational.HibernatePersistenceStrategy" />

<!-- PersistenceService is instantiated here with the actual persistence strategy implementation -->
<bean id="persistenceService" class="org.myProject.persistence.PersistenceService">
    <property name="persistenceStrategy" ref="hibernatePersistenceStrategy"></property>
</bean>
```

In my webapp maven project [4] I do a reference to the actual persistence implementation, e.g. [5] or [6].

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.myProject</groupId>
    <!-- this is where the persistence module is referenced. 
        if you want to change the type of persistence you can do it here. -->
        <artifactId>persistence-relational</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

In my controller classes I can then reference the PersistenceService and the PersistenceStrategy.

```
@Controller
public class NewDatasetController {

    @Autowired
    PersistenceStrategy persistenceStrategy;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String landing() {

        ...
    }
}
```

These pattern are quite nice in my opinion. If you want to add something to this post please feel free.

Comment: I don't quite see a usage of PersistenceService

Comment: The advantage of the PersistenceService would be to have a central object to obtain the persistenceStrategy-object from. But you are right. I guess you can also rename the 'hibernatePersistenceStrategy'-Bean to 'persistenceStrategy' and @Autowire it where you need it and stay 'abstract' to the actual implementation in that way too.